# How to change url of webview with click of a button?

Tags: java, android, webview

So, I'm fairly new to Android development and decided - after some fiddling at first - to make my first complete app an app with a navigation drawer. Ideally I want a WebView of which the url changes if you choose an item in the navigation drawer. E.g.: The navigation drawer consists of the list: Google, Stackoverflow, Facebook and Twitter. If you click on one of them the correct url is pushed to the webview.

I started off with code from Google. A sample app with navigation drawer, with images of planets. I changed some stuff around, but the step I'm currently stuck on is the one where you click an item and the webview changes. Below you can see some snippets of the code:

**fragment_planet.xml**

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="32dp" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

I hope someone can help me out with this, because I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is `loadUrl` method in `Webview` class. It can be called any time you want. Just define method in you `PlanetFragment` for call `loadUrl` method inside it.